# Неопределенный шаблонный класс как аргумент функции

Tags: c++

Скажите пожалуйста, как отправить в функцию неопределенный шаблонный класс?
Речь об этом:

```
double function(vector<typename T> V) {}
```

или хотя бы

```
double function(vector<> V) {}
```

То есть мне не важен сам шаблонный тип вектора. В функции буду работать со стандартными контейнерными методами (insert например).
Да и вообще - реально ли это? Ведь программа не будет знать, сколько памяти выделить...

Comment: попробуйте ее определить как

    template< typename T >
    double function(std::vector<typename T> V) {
      //....
    }

Comment: Шаблонными бывают не только классы, но и функции и методы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен template template parameter. Он объявляется, например, так:

```
template<class, class> class Container // Container -- темплейт с двумя параметрами
```

Вот [рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/rZs610):

```
template<template<class, class> class Container, class T>
void print(const Container<T, allocator<T> >& container)
{
    for (const auto& item : container)
        cout << item << endl;
}
```